# Angular loading wrong resources path when deploying in IIS-6

Tags: angular, iis-6

I run the following command

```
ng build --base-href /extDataAngular/
```

and put all the file from Dist folder to IIS-6 server

When I try to open the Url in Browser

It just show the following error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/runtime.js
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/polyfills.js
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/styles.js
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/scripts.js
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/vendor.js
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/main.js
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Git/assets/img/icon_logo.ico
```

Is there anyway to fix the resource path pointing to the right path?

Correct path should be://d:/app/extDataAngular

Current wrong path: //C:/Program%20Files/Git/extDataAngular/vendor.js

Comment: Can you share the folder structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason...it's because --href this tag for ng build didn't work for me
after build the file I have to alert the  in the index.html

Answer (score 2):

If you run the terminal from the root folder of your project try just running
'ng build --prod' to be sure you are getting the correct files in the build.

Also in IIS make sure the website's physical path is pointing to the d:/app/extDataAngular folder containing the build in the 'Basic Settings' for that site.

[image]

Might be worth looking at updating your IIS installation to IIS 10 also if possible.

Hope this helps!